# Merge Duplicate Paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to compare and merge identical paths. I am following along with [this example](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/comparing-relationship-properties-within-a-path/), but it is only comparing each element in a path to a constant.

My problem is as follows. Consider three graphs

```
a->b->c->d
b->c->d
a->b->c->e
```

Created by the query `CREATE p = (:x {name: 'a'}) -[:next]-> (:y {name: 'b'})-[:next]-> (:x {name: 'c'})-[:next]-> (:y {name: 'd'}), q = (:y {name: 'b'})-[:next]-> (:x {name: 'c'})-[:next]-> (:y {name: 'd'}), r = (:x {name: 'a'}) -[:next]-> (:y {name: 'b'})-[:next]-> (:x {name: 'c'})-[:next]-> (:y {name: 'e'}) RETURN *`

I want to find and then merge all equivalent paths so that I get:

```
a->b->c->d
      |
      v
      e
```

My current idea for an approach is using a query to collect all identical paths in lists and then merging the overlapping nodes and relationships in the paths. For example, I want a query to get

```
[ 
  [ [b-c-d, b-c-d], [a-b-c, a-b-c] ] // comparison of path 1 to paths 2 and 3
  [ [b-c, b-c] ] // comparison of paths 2 and 3
]
```

Then I want to extract all unique nodes and merge them using apoc.refactor.mergeNodes. Followed by apoc.refactor.mergeRelationships on relationships connecting the now identical nodes.

Is this the correct approach? How would I construct a query to obtain the overlapping paths?

Comment: Have you tried https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.refactor/apoc.refactor.mergeRelationships/?
APOC installation is detailed here: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/installation/

Comment: @fbiville I can only merge once I have equivalent paths in lists. I need [b-c-d, b-c-d] in a list, then I can use apoc.refactor functions.

Comment: I assumed that the node labels you described identify unique nodes, however your CREATE query is producing 2 "a" nodes, 3 "c" nodes and so on... They aren't really duplicates, and my answer suggesting to collect distinct does not apply in this case